# Vue js - Set alt image when image source not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a site which has a list of products. Each product has a corresponding image. I am binding the image url to the source attribute like below.

```
<img :src="product.ImageUrl"/>
```

If the image is not found, I want to show a default image.

I do as below in cshtml razor syntax (for reference only)

```
onerror='this.onerror = null;this.src = "@Url.Content("~/images/photo-not-available.jpg")";'
```

How do I achieve the same in Vue?

Comment: `<img :src="" @error="aVueFunctionThatChangesTheSrc">` or even [do it using CSS](https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/).

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set an `onerror` handler function with `@error` in Vue:

```
<img :src="" @error="aVueFunctionThatChangesTheSrc">
```

Answer (score 8):

Since in pure js put onerror inline like this

```
<img :src="ImgUrl" onerror="this.src='http://example.com/default.jpg'"/>
```

for vue.js we can replace it

```
<img :src="ImgUrl" @error="$event.target.src='http://example.com/default.jpg'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing the src in the @error function kicked off a horrible endless loop of updates, causing a flickering screen etc.  My solution so far is:

```
<span v-if="props.column.field === 'avatar'">
  <span v-if="props.row.avatar">
    <img alt="avatar" class="round-32" :src="`${props.row.avatar}`" @error="(() => props.row.avatar = null)"/>
  </span>
  <span v-else>
    <img alt="avatar" class="round-32" src="../../../assets/images/avatar-2.jpg"/>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have try to using @error but it doesn't work because in my case, the image was not found, so I try this one, and its work.

```
<img :src="getImgUrl(filename)">

methods: {
    getImgUrl(filename){
      try{ 
        return require(`@/assets/${filename}`)
      }catch(_){
        return require(`@/assets/default.png`)
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a directive to set a fallback image and prevent the loop:

image-src-fallback.js

```
const setSrc = (evt) => {
  const el = evt.currentTarget;
  el.setAttribute("src", el.fallback);
  el.fallback = "";
  el.removeEventListener("error", _listener);
};

const _listener = (evt) => setSrc(evt);

export default {
  bind(el, binding) {
    el.fallback = binding.value;
    el.addEventListener("error", _listener);
  },

  unbind(el) {
    el.removeEventListener("error", _listener);
  },
};
```

Global import

```
import imageSrcFallback from "./directives/image-src-fallback.js";
Vue.directive("src-fallback", imageSrcFallback);
```

Use

```
<img
  v-src-fallback="user.avatar_fallback_url"
  :src="user.avatar_url"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can create a method, for example in my case some images are not found because clients have not uploaded images, then you can create a method for it: you can return any value as an image or simple '' for any image.

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              class="h-72 w-full object-cover"
              :src="showFirstImageGallery(p.project_images)"
            />
          </div>

methods: {
    showFirstImageGallery(v){
        if (v.length > 1) {
            return v[1].img_url
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    }
  },
```